# What can't be expressed as a linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Say I have outcome variable $Y_i$ and predictors $X_{i1}$ and $X_{i2}$ for some data point $i$. Wikipedia says that a model is linear when:

> the mean of the response variable is a linear combination of the parameters (regression coefficients) and the predictor variables.

I *thought* this meant that a model can be no more complicated than: $Y_i = \beta_1 X_{i1} + \beta_2 X_{i2}$. However, upon further reading, I found out you could handle non-linear "interactions" of the predictors like in $Y_i = \beta_1 X_{i1} + \beta_2 X_{i2} + \beta_3 X_{i1}\ X_{i2}$ by viewing $X_{i1}\ X_{i2}$ as just another predictor (which happens to be dependent on $X_{i1}$ and $X_{i2}$).  This seems to mean that you can use any (linear or non-linear) function of the predictors like $\log(X_{i1} / X_{i2}^2)$ or whatever.  Conceptually, this type of "recoding" seems like it should work for the coefficients as well.

So: What exactly are the limits of linear regression, given you can do this kind of manipulation?

Comment: Shouldn't the question title be "What can't be expressed as a linear model?"?

Comment: Hahaha, yes, you are right. Though most people seemed to have gotten what I meant :-)

Comment: To better understand why your regression equations can be called 'linear', it may help you to read my answer here: [Why is polynomial regression considered a special case of multiple linear regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/7290)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter needs to enter linearly into the equation. So something like $E(Y)=\beta_1 \cos(\beta_2 x_i + \beta_3)$ would not qualify. But you can take functions of the independent variables as follows:

$E(Y)=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \beta_2X^2 + \beta_3 e^{X_i}$

for example.

So the limits of linear regressions are: the mean of the $Y$ values is of the form parameter times (independent variable stuff) + parameter times (more independent variable stuff) ... and so on.

Comment: Sorry for my math-ineptitude but what is the official definition of "entering linearly" into an equation?

Comment: user2243865: The parameters enter linearly when they see it as a [linear function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_linear_map). In the second equation, that's the case, but it isn't in the first equation.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was confused -- linear means it only needs to be "linear in" the coefficients.

Comment: user2243865: It's also "linear in the entered predictors". The term $\beta_3e^{x}$ is not linear in $x$, but it *is* linear in the thing $\beta_3$ is the coefficient for ($e^{x}$), which is what gets supplied as the fourth column of the X-matrix. In matrix notation, $E(Y)=X\beta$ is linear in both $\beta$ and $X$.... it's just that the columns of $X$ aren't necessarily linear in some variable, $x$, which is how linear models can fit some forms of nonlinear relationships.

Comment: Placidia: neither of your equations can be true if there's any noise (/error) in your observations (without which why would we need regression at all?). You either need an error term on the RHS or to put an expectation on the LHS.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was just thinking about the expression for the expected value.

Answer (score 5):

(Almost) Everything can be expressed as a linear model, if you don't restrict it to a finite number of parameters.

This is the basis of functional analysis and kernel regression (as in SVMs with kernels).  For instance, Fourier series - you can produce an infinite sine/cosine series, where the amplitude of the wave of each frequency gets a learned coefficient, and you can learn (almost) any function (any function whose square is integrable - which is a *very* weak condition).

Kernel machines, and functional analysis, are a wonderful idea, and make the world seem very beautiful - virtually everything is linear!

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_methods

The classic statistical probabilistic reference is Grace Wahba's **Spline Models for Observational Data**.

Comment: I've only heard of kernels in random and seemingly unrelated places, like for kernel density estimation and convolutions in general. Do you have any recommendations for literature from a more mathematical/probabilistic point-of-view? (as opposed to algorithm/computer science perspectives, which I have a harder time digesting).

Comment: I upvoted this for the sheer boldness of the assertion. Mathematics is full of approximation theorems of this sort. But the fact remains that non-linearity is real, with distinct characteristics of its own. An approximation is only good for as far as it goes. And as a practical matter, I do like to limit my models to a finite number of parameters.

Comment: user2243865: I updated the post with your reference

Comment: Placidia: Actually, Fourier and functional analysis are not approximation results, but show that wide classes of functions (i.e. square integrable) can be represented *exactly* by infinite linear models.

Approximation comes in where you can regularization/take the first n terms of the series, etc., and come close, so that you have a finite model with low approximation error.

Comment: @Joe, I get that. But I'm old fashioned, and when I studied pure mathematics, back the day, infinite series were always addressed as the limits of finite series. So concretely, you are always dealing with a finite series. But even if you could take an infinite series, typically those convergence results only apply on a compact set. Outside that region, the approximand could differ a lot ielike feedback loops, tipping points and singularites, are essentially non-linear behaviours, which perhaps deserve non-linear models.