# What does "curvilinear" mean?

Tags: linear-model, nonlinear-regression, terminology, definition

As far as I can tell, *curvilinear* is defined vaguely but means the same as *nonlinear*. Is that correct? Or does *curvilinear* have a distinct definition?

Comment: I'd interpret it to mean "not linear (in the sense of being curved, not 'linear in parameters') at least continuous and in some sense, smooth" (where smooth might mean something like 'continuous first derivative' perhaps, but there may be other definitions that would feel like they were in keeping with the sense of the word). So I wouldn't call a linear spline 'curvilinear', but I'd certainly call a cubic spline 'curvilinear' (even though it's linear in the sense that it can be fitted with linear regression).

Comment: Strongly related: [How to tell the difference between linear and non-linear regression models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148638/)

Answer (score 14):

"Nonlinear" has many meanings, only some of which are (directly) about curves. I would say that I have encountered "curvilinear" to mean smooth curves. So a parabola or a logarithmic curve are "curvilinear," but a bent line (e.g. from a simple threshold or saturation model, "broken stick" model, etc.) are not.

Caveat emptor: word use will vary by context. For example straight lines are themselves a kind of "curve" in some contexts. As always, if there is a specific usage of the word "curvilinear" that you are wondering about, a quote and citation or two would be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

The lack of clear and consistent terminology is one of my pet peeves, but I don't see how there is any real solution.  For what it's worth, I often use certain words in a vague and [hand wavy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handwavy) way to get at general ideas when I don't want to take on all the baggage of technically defined terms (e.g., "variability" instead of *variance*).  I have used "curvilinear" similarly.  I do like @Alexis' description.  If you wanted a more precisely defined version, I might posit that *rectilinear* would be a [smooth function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html) where the [second derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) is $0$ everywhere, and that *curvilinear* is a smooth function where the second derivative is **not** $0$ everywhere.

I do want to note that "curvilinear" and *non-linear* should **not** be considered synonymous in statistics.  In statistics (e.g., regression modeling) "linear" is shorthand for *[linear in the parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_model#Linear_regression_models)*.  That is, all the parameters being estimated enter into the model as coefficients.  On the other hand, "non-linear" means that the estimated parameters **do not** all enter into the model as coefficients.  There are many cases where a function looks 'curvilinear' but is **not** non-linear (e.g., adding a squared term to a regression model).  This is a subtle point and it trips up a lot of students, so it is worth always stating explicitly.  For more on how a model that looks 'curvilinear' can still be a *linear model*, it may help to read my answer here:  [Why is polynomial regression considered a special case of multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/7290)

Comment: Chiming into this excellent answer to add that another meaning of "nonlinear" or "non-linear" is full or partial integration where $y_{t} = y_{<t} + \text{Other Deterministic Stuff} + \text{Random Process Stuff}$. That is models of variables that are functions of their past values are also (sometimes, perhaps often) labeled "non-linear".

Comment: @Alexis, you're right that it is used in still another way in time-series. I stuck with the regression context here. Maybe I should mention time-series in the answer? (I have relatively little expertise in TS, though.)

Comment: All good either way, although time series analysis *is* regression... just regression with particular operators the way I think about it.

Comment: @gung I understand that "nonlinear" means the relationship between Y and the parameters is not linear, so polynomial models are "linear" even though a graph of X vs. Y is curved. But where does "curvilinear" fit. Is a polynomial function curvilinear? How about a true nonlinear function?

Answer (score 2):

To me, in the context of data analysis, it is always linked with the idea of leaning a topographic mapping of the data, so that samples that are mapped close by, are similar in a given sense. The wikipedia site on [Nonlinear dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) offers a nice overview. THe paper [Laplacian eigenmaps and Spectral Techniques for Embedding and Clustering](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mbelkin/papers/LEM_NIPS_01.pdf) contains a nice description of a framework where the idea of manifold learning is linked with differential geometry.

In other words, curvilinear is to me related to the problem of learning a distance metric from data. The hypothesis is that the data lies in a smooth, low dimensional manifold. That learned metric correspond to the metric tensor as in the [classical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) of the term.

Answer (score -1):

A Curvilinear Relationship is a type of relationship between two variables where as one variable increases, so does the other variable, but only up to a certain point, after which, as one variable continues to increase, the other decreases. If you were to graph this kind of curvilinear relationship, you will come up with an inverted-U. The other type of curvilinear relationship is one where as one variable increases, the other decreases up to a certain point, after which, both variables increase together. This will give you a U-shaped curve.

An example of a curvilinear relationship would be staff cheerfulness and customer satisfaction. The more cheerful a service staff is, the higher the customer satisfaction, but only up to a certain point. When a service staff is too cheerful, it might be perceived by customers as fake or annoying, bringing down their satisfaction level.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Bonnie. Although plausible (and well explained), this answer seems like a much more restricted sense of "curvilinear" than I have ever encountered.  Behaviors like the ones you describe are often referred to as "U-shaped."  Would you by any chance have a popular and accessible reference in mind that supports your definition?