# Why can $R^2$ be expressed as a quadratic form?

Tags: multiple-regression

Somewhere I saw that the coefficient-of-determination for the multiple linear regression is given by the following quadratic form:

$$R^2 = \boldsymbol{r}_{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{r}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}}^{-1} \boldsymbol{r}_{\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}}$$

where $r_{y,x}$ is the correlation matrix of x with y and $r_{x,x}$ is the correlation matrix of x.

I don't see why this is the case and I haven't found a proof anywhere. Can someone show me why this is? It doesn't seem immediately related to the ratio of sums of squares.

Comment: What does `the correlation matrix of x with y` mean when there are multiple features, as [tag:multiple-regression] implies? // If the situation is just a simple linear regression with only one feature, then $r_{x, x}^{-1} = 1$, and there is no need to include that middle term.

Comment: There's a detailed answer in another thread: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314926/can-you-calculate-r2-from-correlation-coefficents-in-multiple-linear-regressi/364630#364630]

Comment: @Eli Yes, but anent this point all that answer states is "it can be shown."  The demonstration would follow the one I gave for the covariance-based solution at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597: after standardizing the variables, all covariances become correlations and you're most of the way there.