# R squared and higher order polynomial regression

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, r-squared

The plot below shows the saturation of a road against the impact on journey time (normalized to free flow journey time).

The blue (BPR function) curve presents a standardized model used in the field to relate journey time and saturation.

For the empirical data I gathered, I plotted a third order polynomial fit, shown in red. In order to assess this fit, I found the $R^2$ for this third order fit. This was given as 0.72.

I talked to a colleague about $R^2$ and he pointed me to this article. [Why Is There No R-Squared for Nonlinear Regression?](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression)

I have found many articles were $R^2$ is used to assess the fit of a higher order polynomial and I am now rather confused.

Is $R^2$ inappropriate in this case? What should I use instead?

[image]

Comment: Polynomial regression is linear - it is the coefficients that determine the linearity of the model, not the model matrix. Actually, [check this fantastic post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/67822). So I think you are on the right path.

Comment: Thank you @AntoniParellada. That made for excellent reading. I am also selfishly glad as I do not need to redo some analyses ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a polynomial:

$$ \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \ldots + \beta_k x^k$$

Observe that the polynomial is non-linear in $x$ but that it is [*linear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) in $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. If we're trying to estimate $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, this is linear regression! 
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + \ldots + \beta_k x_i^k + \epsilon_i$$
Linearity in $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_k)$ is what matters. When estimating the above equation by least squares, all of the results of linear regression will hold.

Let $\mathit{SST}$ be the total sum of squares, $\mathit{SSE}$ be the explained sum of squares, and $\mathit{SSR}$ be the residual sum of squares. The [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) $R^2$ is defined as:

$$ R^2 = 1 - \frac{\mathit{SSR}}{\mathit{SST}}$$

And the result of linear regression that $\mathit{SST} = \mathit{SSE} + \mathit{SSR}$ gives $R^2$ it's familiar interpretation as the fraction of variance explained by the model.

### SST = SSE + SSR: When is it true and when is it not true?

Let $\hat{y}_i$ be the forecast value of $y_i$ and let $e_i = y_i - \hat{y}_i$ be the residual. Furthermore, let's define the demeaned forecast value as $f_i = \hat{y}_i - \bar{y}$.

Let $\langle ., . \rangle$ denote an [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html). Trivially we have:
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{e}, \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{e} \rangle &= \langle \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{f} \rangle + 2\langle \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{e} \rangle + \langle \mathbf{e}, \mathbf{e} \rangle \\
&= \langle \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{f} \rangle + \langle \mathbf{e}, \mathbf{e} \rangle \quad \quad\text{if $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{e}$ orthogonal, i.e. their inner product is 0}
\end{align*}
Observe that $\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle = \sum_i a_i b_i$ is a valid inner product. Then we have:

- $\langle \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{e}, \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{e} \rangle = \sum_i \left(y_i - \bar{y} \right)^2 $ is the total sum of squares (SST).
- $\langle \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{f} \rangle = \sum_i \left(\hat{y}_i - \bar{y} \right)^2$ is the explained sum of squares (SSE).
- $\langle \mathbf{e}, \mathbf{e} \rangle = \sum_i \left(y_i - \hat{y}_i \right)^2 $ is the residual sum of squares (SSR).

Thus $SST = SSE + SSR$ is true if the demeaned forecast $\mathbf{f}$ is [orthogonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthogonal.html) to the residual $\mathbf{e}$. This is true in ordinary least squares linear regression whenever a constant is included in the regression. Another interpretation of ordinary least squares is that you're [projecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) $\mathbf{y}$ onto the [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of regressors, hence the residual is orthogonal to that space by construction. Orthogonality of right hand side variables and residuals is not in general true for forecasts $\hat{y}_i$ obtained in other ways.