# What is the difference between linear regression and polynomial regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

I'm currently experimenting with different regression techniques on this data set that I have, and I some sources state a method called "polynomial regression". I looked it up and I can't really find any clear explanation of what it is exactly. It sounds quite similar to linear regression - can anyone tell me the difference (if any)?

Thanks!

Comment: See gung's detailed explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92065/why-is-polynomial-regression-considered-a-special-case-of-multiple-linear-regres/92087#92087)

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomial regression is a form of linear regression where higher order powers (2nd, 3rd or higher) of an independent variable are included.