# Why the blue line of a regression model is not a linear line?

Tags: regression, logistic

For the following regression model,
$$
y=\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1\cdot|m(a)-m(b)|+\sum_{k=0}^{12}\hat{\beta}_{k} 1[|m(a)-m(b)=k|]
$$
The fitting plot not a linear.

Why the blue line (that is fitted using a regression model that assumes a linear trend) is not a linear line?

Comment: The blue line obviously is *not* a linear function of the horizontal axis.  Please explain to us what your notation means.  What are "$m(a)$" and "$m(b)$"??

Comment: Also, what is $y$ doing in there? Can you edit your post to include the parameter estimates? The part on the right, with the indicator function, seems to fit six-month cycles (since $k$ goes up to $6$), but with the absolute values in there, it may also yield the 12-month periodicity of the blue line. Also, why does your question carry the [tag:logistic] tag? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Too much information is omitted to make sense of this. Please give more context.

Comment: It may help you to read my answer to [Why is polynomial regression considered a special case of multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/7290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Linear" regression estimate coefficients in order to explain the response of a variable $Y$ to changes in variables $X_k$ using a linear equation of the form $Y=X\beta$. Ex:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1, i} + \beta_2 x_{2, i} + \epsilon_i$$

"Linear" refers to the fact that $\mathbb{E}(y_i)$ is defined as a linear combination of the parameters $\beta$, not necessarily $X$, which could be modified depending on your objectives/interpretations of the data. Indeed, if some variables $X_k$ are "transformed" variables derived from your actual variable of interest, then the responses will not be linear, but you are still using a linear regression model. Ex:

\begin{split}
y_i &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1, i} + \beta_2 x_{2, i} + \epsilon_i\\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 t_{i}^2 + \beta_2 \sqrt{t_{i}} + \epsilon_i
\end{split}

With the equation above, $\mathbb{E}(y_i)$ is defined as a linear combination of parameters $\beta$ and of transformed variables $X_k$. But it is not a linear combination of the actual variable of interest, time $t$, which has a non-linear impact on your dependent variable $Y$.

This is what is happening in your case, where your variables $X_k$ are non-linear functions of time $t$, since you introduced absolute values of time differences and binary variables depending on the time of each observation.

Comment: Thanks! In Wiki, is says "Linearity. This means that the mean of the response variable is a linear combination of the parameters (regression coefficients) and the predictor variables." in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression. What do you mean $E(y_i)$ is a linear combination of $\beta$ and $X$?

Comment: You're welcome! 

Indeed, but in my second equation, the predictors of the linear regression are the variables $X_k$. So these 2 sentences have the same meaning.