# conceptual understanding of quadratic regression

Tags: regression

It's clear to me how to interpret the coefficients of a quadratic regression:

```
data <- data.frame(hours=c(6, 9, 12, 14, 30, 35, 40, 47, 51, 55, 60),
                   happiness=c(14, 28, 50, 70, 89, 94, 90, 75, 59, 44, 27))

data$hours2 <- data$hours^2

quadraticModel <- lm(happiness ~ hours + hours2, data=data)

summary(quadraticModel)



           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -18.25364    6.18507  -2.951   0.0184 *  
hours         6.74436    0.48551  13.891 6.98e-07 ***
hours2       -0.10120    0.00746 -13.565 8.38e-07 ***

happinessPredict <- predict(quadraticModel,list(hours=hourValues, hours2=hourValues^2))

plot(data$hours, data$happiness, pch=16)
lines(hourValues, happinessPredict, col='blue')
```

however, what isn't clear is why this works. Both `hours` and `hours2` increase ever more positively. How does squaring `hours` and add it to the model allow to capture the quadratic trend?

Is there anyone who could provide me with a non-mathematical explanation for this?

Comment: "*Both `hours` and `hours2` have a positive relationship with happiness.*". Plotting your data will show this is false. Or even just look at the values: `happiness` peaks at `hours` = 35 and then declines i.e. it has a unimodal relationship.

Comment: It is difficult to conceive of a "non-mathematical" way to explain, with any semblance of accuracy, the purely mathematical concept of a quadratic formula.  Geometric explanations can be offered, as well as algebraic ones, but anything non-mathematical would be so non-quantitative as to be of doubtful value.  One of the more constructive ways you can approach this situation is to plot some quadratic functions.

Comment: @mkt, yes, that's right. I actually wanted to write that `hours` and `hours2` both show a positive increase, and that it's confusing to me how `hours2` can change the direction of the predictions

Comment: @whuber, yes, maybe I shouldn't have used the term "non-mathematical". I understand it's probably difficult to explain this in a purely conceptual way. I just wanted to avoid answers with loads of formulas that for a non-statistician like myself wouldn't be very helpful understanding the issue I'm having

Comment: One thing I realised from reading this question and @EdM's excellent answer is that I was trying to think of `hours` and `hours2` being two separate predictors, when in fact it's one predictor with a quadratic and linear term. I think lots of learning resources on quadratic regression say to 'just add' the quadratic term to the regression to see if it improves fit etc., as if it was a different variable

Comment: Related: [Does it make sense to add a quadratic term but not the linear term to a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/28730/7290), & [Why is polynomial regression considered a special case of multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92065/7290)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The individual associations of your `hours` and `hours2` with `happiness` are extremely weak in your example, and nothing completely "non-mathematical" can explain this. Maybe the following plot can help illustrate how multiple regression allows the predictor `hours2` to improve on predictions based solely on `hours`.

[image: plot of data, models, and components]

The values are circles. The dashed black line shows the linear association of `happiness` with `hours` alone. Not very good, not even "statistically significant" (p = 0.53 for the `hours` coefficient).

The solid black line shows the full model. You might think of this as starting with a linear extrapolation of the values near `hours = 0`, shown in the blue line. You might then think of the (squared) `hours2` term as providing a non-linear correction to that extrapolation. Subtract the red curve from the blue line and you get the full model.

Code in R:

```
plot(happiness~hours,data,bty="n",xlim=c(0,60),ylim=c(0,300))
abline(lm(happiness~hours,data),lty=2)
abline(-18.2536,6.7444,col="blue") # "extrapolation" from 'hours' near 0
curve(.1012*x^2,from=0,to=60,add=TRUE,col="red") # non-linear "correction"
curve(-18.2536+6.7444*x-0.1012*x^2,from=0,to=60,add=TRUE) # full model
legend("topleft",bty="n",
        legend="black dashed, linear 'hours' alone
               \nblack solid, full model
               \nblue, 'hours' component, full model
               \nred, negative of 'hours2' component, full model")
```

Comment: Many thanks @EdM, that's definitely helpful in visualizing it! I just don't get why the curve for `hours2` is `.1012*x^2` and not `-18.2536 - .1012*x^2`, since this would be the regression equation for `hours2` when `hours=0` wouldn't it?

Comment: @locus the model is `y=-18.2536 +6.7444*x- .1012*x^2`. For illustration I combined the first 2 terms (intercept and `x` term) in the blue line and showed them separately from the second `x^2` term, then plotted the (negative of) the second term separately as the red line. If I included the intercept with the second term instead for the red line, I would have had to remove it from the formula for the blue line and that line's close agreement with the values at low `x`  wouldn't have been obvious. For this model the "regression equation" when `x=0` doesn't make sense, as then `x^2=0` also.