# What does 'linear' word in multiple linear regression and linearity assumption in multiple linear regression mean?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I am studying linear regression. I want to ask is the linear word in multiple linear regression refers to the linear relationship between the target variable and each of the regression coefficients b_0, b_1,b_2, ..., b_n? Also in multiple linear regression there is a linearity assumption does this assumption refers to the linear relationship between the dependent variable and each independent variables which we confirm using scatter plot?

MLR equation that I am using:

$\hat y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \dots + b_n x_n$

Also if this linearity assumption is not satisfied should I then try polynomial regression? And is this polynomial regression also a kind of linear regression where the independent variable is non-linearly related to dependent variable but the regression coefficients are linearly related to target variable?

I know I have asked too many doubts so please bear with me and be kind to clear my doubts.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/247274) answer your question? If not, why not? What questions remain?

Comment: The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638 provides some information for disambiguating the various senses of "linear" you refer to.